# WebApi XML Deserialization - Node with multiple child nodes is not correctly deserialized as array of childnode objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to deserialize an XML by POST-ing it to an WebApi POST method. Everything works fine and deserializes okay, except for a node with multiple child nodes.

The code looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class grandparentnode
{
    [XmlElement]
    public parentnode[] parentnode { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class parentnode
{
    public childnode childnode { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class childnode
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
    public string baz { get; set; }
}
```

This is the XML:

```
<grandparentnode>
    <parentnode>
        <childnode>
            <foo>1</foo>
            <bar>2</bar>
            <baz>3</baz>
        </childnode>
        <childnode>
            <foo>4</foo>
            <bar>5</bar>
            <baz>6</baz>
        </childnode>
        <childnode>
            <foo>7</foo>
            <bar>8</bar>
            <baz>9</baz>
        </childnode>
    </parentnode>
</grandparentnode>
```

The problem is, that on debug, all that I get is one item in the `parentnode[]` array, like this: `{WebApiListener.Controllers.FooBarBazController.parentnode[1]}`. I would need parentnode as an array of childnode objects.

Any idea why?

Thank you,
*Peter*

Comment: Your childnode property is no array.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing some closing and opening tags. What about now? If it's not an array, then what it should be represented as?

Comment: The "childnode" property of your parentnode should be of type childnode[] and it should be marked with the [XmlElement] attribute, i would guess.

Comment: And you would be wrong. childnode is an object with foo,bar and baz properties. I need and array of childnode objects. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I'll try to explain better. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Judging from the xml the parentnode can have more than one childnode, yet the class only can hold exactly one childnode. And its missing the [XmlElement] attribute.

Comment: You were right! I mixed up the order and thus creating an array of single nodes that can contain only one item. Silly me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @Jobo pointed out, I mixed up the order in which the array should be deserialized.

This is the modified code:

```
[Serializable]
public class grandparentnode
{
    public parentnode parentnode { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class parentnode
{
    [XmlElement]
    public childnode[] childnode { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class childnode
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
    public string baz { get; set; }
}
```