# How to deserialize XML elements with variable number of children?

Tags: xml, f#, xml-parsing, c#-to-f#

Minimal-ish example of the XML being deserialized, let's call it `newyorker.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Periodical subscription="true" issues_per_year="47">
        <Title>The New Yorker</Title>
        <Website>newyorker.com</Website>

        <Edition available="true" date="2018-04-16">
            <Contributor>Junot Diaz</Contributor>
            <Contributor>Louisa Thomas</Contributor>
            <Contributor>D. T. Max </Contributor>
            <!-- More contributors omitted -->
        </Edition>

        <Edition available="true" date="...">
            <Contributor>David Remnick</Contributor>
            <Contributor>Malcolm Gladwell</Contributor>
            <!-- More contributors omitted -->
        </Edition>

       <!-- More editions omitted -->
    </Periodical>
    <Other>
        <Foo>Foo</Foo>
        <Foo>Bar</Foo>
    </Other>
</Root>
```

Deserialization code:

```
open System.Xml
open System.Xml.Serialization

let Deserialize<'T> file rootnode =
    file |> File.ReadAllText
         |> (fun data -> new StringReader(data))
         |> (new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof<'T>, new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(rootnode))).Deserialize
```

Current definitions of `Edition` and `Periodical` types:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Edition = {
    [<XmlAttribute("available")>] Available : bool
    [<XmlAttribute("date")>]   Date : string
    [<XmlElement>]   Contributor : string list // What goes here? 
}

[<CLIMutable>]
type Periodical = {
    [<XmlAttribute("subscription")>]      Subscription : bool
    [<XmlAttribute("issues_per_year")>]   IssuesPerYear: int
    [<XmlElement>] Title: string
    [<XmlElement>] Website : string
    [<XmlElement>] Edition : Edition list   // What goes here?
}
```

My goal is to deserialize the file into the `Periodical` node. Is this possible using `XmlSerializer`? If so, how should I adjust the definitions of `Periodical` and `Edition` to make this work? In C#, it [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14120786/7418646) that this can be done by declaring `Periodical` to contain an array of `Edition` (and `Edition` to contain an array of `Contributor`) - but I have not been able to get this to work in F#.

(I am aware of `XmlDocument` and `XDocument`. This question is specifically about `XmlSerializer`. Also, it is probably not feasible to modify the arrangement of the XML file due to legacy reasons.)

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error? Have you tried defining Edition as `Edition []` (array of additions), and Contributor as `string []`, (string array)?

Comment: Yes. A `Periodical` record with default values is returned. `{Subscription = false;
 IssuesPerYear = 0;
 Title = null;
 Website = null;
 Edition = null;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Edition = {
    ...
    [<XmlElement>]   Contributor : string array
}

[<CLIMutable>]
type Periodical = {
    ...
    [<XmlElement>] Edition : Edition array
}

let p = Deserialize<Periodical[]> "test.xml" "Root"
```

works for me

Comment: You're right. I was doing `Deserialize<Periodical> "test.xml" "Root"`, which kept returning with empty/default values. Any insight on why this might be the case?

Comment: Don't know much about it, to be honest - I made your example work just by trying many different tweaks. The best guess I have is that XML structure should map class/property structure and as for the Periodical/Edition and Edition/Contributor the relation is defined, for the Root/Periodical it is not. I _think_ that `Deserialize<Periodical>` tries to deserialise from root. Perhaps <Root subscription="true" issues_per_year="47"> will set the properties.